# Get contact information of system administrator from the terminal

Tags: command-line, email, administration

Do any of the common Unix/Linux platforms provide a way to query the system administrator contact information from the command line. Obviously a system admin might not include this information when they set up the server, but is there a way to ask for it when it is there (e.g., name or email)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming there's no organizational procedure, you can't ask your coworkers, and you don't know the company who runs the server...

You could see if there's any contact information when you log in, e.g. in `/etc/issue`, `/etc/motd`

Or you could try emailing `root@<this hostname>`.

Or you could look at who is in the `root` or `wheel` group, and contact them.  Either they are the system administrator, or they know who is.  You can get their info with e.g. `getent group 0`, `getent passwd <username>`, and maybe `finger`.

Comment: The non-terminal-based procedures that you mentioned are available to me, I was just hoping there was a more direct route to obtaining that info (for future reference). Thanks for the helpful commands anyway.

Answer (score 4):

The standard way to provide this information was by putting it in the [GECOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gecos_field) field of `/etc/passwd` (the 5th field before the home directory of a user). E.g¹:

```
root:pPHgdObrveALw:0:0:Anthon van der Neut,101a,+31 70 262631,+31 70 262699:/root:/bin/sh
```

The comma-separated GECOS field contained:

- real user name²
- room
- phone
- other

In this case there was a fax number but no email in the other field.

There is no obligation to fill this out, but if your administrator has done so, this is where you can read it from with `grep 'root:' /etc/passwd` or with `finger` (if installed). And if it is information is not available, and proper email forwarding is set up for root, you can always try  emailing `root@localhost` while you are logged into the system.

In my experience, the decline of the usefulness of the GECOS field came with the introduction of personal Unix workstations and security conscious administrators stopping the use of non-essential services (i.e. running a  finger daemon on port 79).

¹ <sub>If I have my old docs straight this was my root entry in `/etc/passwd` on the PDP11-70 I managed in 1984.</sub>
² <sub>On my Ubuntu system the user setup still stores that info there</sub>

Answer (score 2):

No.

Unless the sysadmin explicitly (or naively) put their contact information there's no way.

Comment: It just seems a little strange that a sysadmin wouldn't want to let users know how to contact them in the event that they encounter problems with the machine.

Comment: For that they have phones and emails give in person (or by contact).